# Vue.js, Axios multiple get CORS requests to Laravel API are randomly failing

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I have this problem - on Vue component created life cycle hook I am making 2 CORS get requests via Axios to external Laravel API. If I make only one of the requests everything is fine and it works 100% of the time. But if I make 2 or more requests I sometimes get failed requests on random in the network tab. Obviously I am doing something wrong with Axios. Can you please help me.

This is my component created hook - I call VueX actions.

```js
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getPets');
    this.$store.dispatch('getSpecies');
},
```

And this are my actions in VueX store

```js
actions: {
    getPets(context) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get('api/pets')
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('SET_PETS', response.data);
                    context.commit('SET_SELECTED_PET', response.data.data[0]);

                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    },
    getSpecies(context) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get('api/species')
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('SET_SPECIES', response.data);
                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    },
    setSelectedPet(context, pet) {
        context.commit('SET_SELECTED_PET', pet);
    },
}
```

Then I get failed requests on random - sometimes both requests are ok (200 status),
other times one of them is failing...
[Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbj10.png)

The request is failed - there is no response, I think that the request does not go to the Laravel API at all. Laravel logs are empty too.

I think I am doing something wrong with Axios, because its not from my browser or firewall - I have stopped firewall and tested in incognito and other browsers without any extensions. Any help will be appreciated.

This are the Axios headers I set up in the main js file.

```js
// Set axios to call the backend API and set its headers on every page reload
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://api.aaa';
window.axios.defaults.timeout = 30000;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+getToken(),
};
```

Comment: Click on that error on that image check the response, that will give more insights of the error.  And as far as I know, laravel api routes are free from CORS.

Comment: The request is failed - there is no response, I think that the request does not go to the Laravel API at all. Laravel logs are empty too.

Comment: Can it be that you hae send too many request at that time?

Comment: (1) Where is the server running? (2) Can you try to just make the two responses concurrently in a test method, away from vuex and such? (for example, immediately where you're setting up the headers)

Comment: Small nit in the meantime - if you are just passing the error on, you don't need to write a `catch` - https://pastebin.com/8e0crUZE - this is exactly equivalent to your example actions. **Or**, if you don't use the return value, https://pastebin.com/biAgwTEp

Comment: @SuperDJ Everything is running on localhost. Its not too many request at the time error. My throttle is 600 requests per minute and if I make more I get the 429 Too many attempts error.

Comment: @Mihail Malostanidis I have done this in main.js file and still the same result function getSpecies() {
  return axios.get('api/species');
}

function getPets() {
  return axios.get('api/pets');
}

axios.all([getSpecies(), getPets()]);

Comment: There's no reason to use `axios.all`, it's just `Promise.all`.
My guess is that the server logic you wrote causes a conflict when both requests arrive at the same time. Which is strange since they're just read requests, you're not modifying  anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some  time I finally figured it out. It was the PHP opCache that was causing this behavior. If you have the similar problem just turn opChache off.

Btw can you give me your thoughts about what can cause this behavior from Laravel because I dont want to lose opCache as an option for similar Laravel projects?

Comment: I have the same problem and it boggles my mind that you say OpCache was the issue because you were testing this on localhost? And surely you didn't have opcache enabled on your dev environment?? Are you sure this was it? Also having to disable opcache on prod doesn't seem right